# Return the same type of collection of the same type

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

I am trying to create a method for shuffling a collection. I want it to be generic, which means it should take a specific type of collection (`TCollection`) of elements of type `TEl`. I want the method to return the same type of *collection* containing the same type of *elements* as the parameter.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
internal static TCollection FisherYatesShuffle<TCollection, TEl>(this TCollection objects)
    where TCollection : IEnumerable<TEl>
{
    var ret = new TEl[objects.Count()];
    ret[0] = objects.First();
    var rand = new Random();
    for (var i = 1; i < objects.Count(); i++)
    {
        var j = rand.Next(0, i);
        ret[i] = ret[j];
        ret[j] = objects.ElementAt(i);
    }

    return ret; //CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'TEl[]' to 'TCollection'
  //return (TCollection)ret; //CS0030: Cannot convert type 'TEl[]' to 'TCollection'
}
```

Is the type of generics I am trying to use possible? If it is, how would I have to change my method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use:

```
where TCollection : IList<TEl>, new()
```

And then

```
var result = new TCollection();
...
    result.Add(item)
...
return result;
```

This will not work with arrays though - might need to special-case them.

Comment: although this is a good solution for lists, it doesn't work with `IEnumerable<TEl>` either unless I add `.ToList()`

Comment: @csharpler indeed... But if you are starting from IEnumerable-T all chances of doing it at the compiler level are dead - you don't know any concrete type statically. You would have to use reflection then - and indeed, it could be something like a where-iterator (from Enumerable.Where) - what "collection" would you make then? Since the original **was not a collection**

Comment: that's true, I will stay with `IEnumerable<T>.ToList().Shuffle<List<T>,T>()` although it doesn't look very good, and add a separate case for arrays